# $O(n \log n)$ simple polygon triangulation via divide and conquer

Tags: computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

I am looking for the simplest possible $O(n \log n)$ algorithm for triangulating a simple polygon.  It seems like there should be a simple divide and conquer variant that would fit the bill, ideally one avoiding auxiliary data structures such as trapezoidal decompositions.  Indeed, all that would be required is an $O(n)$ algorithm for finding a roughly balanced diagonal.  However, I am unable to find any algorithms that are as simple as I (perhaps naively) imagine should exist; nearly all the research is focused on $o(n \log n)$ algorithms, nearly all of which operate via trapezoidal decomposition.

Comment: A polygon can be triangulated in *linear* time, though the algorithm (due to Chazelle) is not particularly simple: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/polygon-triang.pdf.

Comment: Yes, linear time is $o(n \log n)$.

Comment: Triangulation by decomposing into monotone pieces avoids the trapezoidal decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

Garey, Johnson, Preparata and Tarjan came up with a simple $O(n\log n)$ algorithm back in 1978. It is described in many lecture notes, for example these [lecture notes](http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/6.838-old/handouts/lec4.pdf) of Piotr Indyk.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that one, though it's essentially doing trapezoidal decomposition.  It's also not really divide and conquer.  It's possible I should get over my allergy to non-rotationally invariant algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for such a diagonal as well. As I could not find a simple way to obtain it we applied a linear time cutting of the polygon ([Sutherland–Hodgman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) approach). Given a simple polygon $P$ we take a vertical line $\ell$ and cut through $P$. This can be done if $O(n)$ time by simply iterating over the boundary list of $P$ and verify if $\ell$ is crossed. This produces a set of sub-polygons. Clearly the number of vertices of the polygons to the left of $\ell$ is equal to the number of vertices on the right side of $\ell$, up to a constant at least. Then we triangulated each sub-polygon. Since there are vertices in the sub-polygons due to the cutting we had to also add a repair step to get rid of these additional vertices. For more details look directly at [our work](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2017.12.001).